# How can I get a the default width of a specified font in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, fonts, width, default

I'm writing a DXF exporter/importer. The DXF MTEXT entity format supports width factor for a text block (how times it is wider than the default font width). The Windows LogFont record contains the lfWidth field (how many pixel will be the average font width if you select the logfont to create a hFont). How can I get the default width of the used font to calculate the scaling factor back and forth? Is there any WinAPI call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I have found It. The getTextMetrics fills up a TEXTMETRIC record. It has a tmAveCharWidth. The searched value.